# How should I insert jQuery code before a submit action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to manipulate form data with jQuery before I submit a form. The code looks like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('Something');
  // What do I put here to make the form submit?
})
```

Comment: What kind of manipulation do you have in mind?

Comment: I am adding a JSON object with jQuery.

Comment: Check the doc https://api.jquery.com/submit/. You can cancel the submit action by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the event object or by returning `false`.

Comment: I want it to submit, but after I do what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

In the hypotesis you have a submit input in the form, you can try this:

```
$('form input[type=submit]').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('Something');
  // make the form submit
  $(this).parents('form').submit();
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It's running an infinite loop of submission calls that just logs the message and does not submit.